# Poor message when reviewing an edit on my own post

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I have just approved an edit on my question on a site where I have low rep.  I got this message.

> Thank you for your review.   You need at least 2k reputation to
>   continue reviewing suggested edits.

This is a very confusing message for someone that does not understand how the review process works.

Comment: What could be improved?

Comment: Given I was not trying to review suggested editS, but just click on the inbox item to say someone had suggested an edit to my post, there is no point saying anything about “continue reviewing…”, just provide a link back to the post that had the edit.

Comment: I think the link in the inbox should not take to the review queue, but the post itself, similarly to when you click the `edit(1)` when there's a suggested edit on a post giving you a popup to review it.

Comment: It could be improved by not confusing reviewing suggested edits for "self-post" with the posts of the community; meaning my understanding it the message should say: "Thank you for your review. You need at least 2k reputation to continue reviewing suggested edits **for posts that were not created by you.**"

Comment: @blunders, why is there an assumption that the user wishes to review any other items?

Comment: @IanRingrose: It's just the way the code is written I'm guessing, that being the assumption is that you're working a que, and per item, it checks to see if you have the access rights to review the item. If you had two "self post" items, which I'm guessing would get a high priority in your own que, then you wouldn't see the messages until after reviewing your own posts. Make sense; meaning I agree it's confusing, and pretty much a bug in my opinion.